# Java Threads errors: Exception in thread error plus Array index out of bounds exception plus Socket Exception / Connection Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating two program files (one client one server).

Each file has one thread (one thread for server, one thread for client)

At runtime, there is supposed to be only one server, and there is supposed to be multiple and/or potentially infinite number of clients connecting to the server at the same time)

In order to get multiple clients to run, the user opens multiple command prompt / mac terminal windows (each window being one client) (one window being the server, so it requires at least two windows to run)

Once a client is connected, it can send messages (utf-8 strings) to the server. It will also receive from the server all messages sent from the other connected clients (it will not receive messages sent from itself).

Screenshot of exception in thread / array index out of bounds error (eclipse):

[image]

Screenshot of Socket Exception error (server):

[image]

Screenshot of error on client side:

[image]

Code of Server (ChatServer.java):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatServer
{
    ChatServer chatserver = new ChatServer();
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread ChatServer1 = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    int port_number1 = 0;
                    int numberOfClients = 0;
                    boolean KeepRunning = true;
                    if(args.length>0)
                    {
                        port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Waiting for connections on port " + port_number1);

                    try 
                    {
                         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                         socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );
                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        //create a list of clients
                        ArrayList<String> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //connect to client
                        // socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        //add new client to the list, is this the right way to add a new client? or should it be in a for loop or something?
                        ListOfClients.add("new client");
                        numberOfClients += 1;

                        System.out.println("A client has connected. Waiting for message...");
                        ListOfClients.add("new client" + numberOfClients);

                        //reading encoded utf-8 message from client, decoding from utf-8 format 
                        String MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8 = "";
                        BufferedReader BufReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedFromUTF8 = BufReader1.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedUTF8 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");


                        //relaying message to every other client besides the one it was from

                        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
                        {
                            if(ListOfClients.get(i)!="new client")
                            {
                                   String newmessage = null;
                                   String returnMessage = newmessage;
                                   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                   bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
                                   System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+returnMessage);
                                   bw.flush();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (socket != null)
                        {
                            socket.close ();
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        ChatServer1.start();
    }
}
```

Code of ChatClient.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{


    static int numberOfClients = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient();

              //If I wanted to create multiple clients, would this code go here? OR should the new thread creation be outside the while(true) loop?
              while (true)
              {
                  String host = "localhost";
                  int numberOfClients = 0;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {   
                          try
                          {

                              //Client begins, gets port number, listens, connects, prints out messages from other clients
                              int port = 0;
                              int port_1number1 = 0;
                              int numberofmessages = 0;
                              String[] messagessentbyotherclients = null;
                              System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                              System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                              String port_number1= args[0];
                              System.out.println("Port number is: " + port_number1);
                              if(args.length>0)
                              {
                                  port = Integer.valueOf(port_number1);
                              }
                              System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                              System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + port_number1 );
                              boolean KeepRunning = true;
                              while(KeepRunning)
                              {
                                  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfClients; i++)
                                  {
                                      System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);
                                  }
                                  try 
                                  {
                                      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                      InetAddress inetlocalhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                                      SocketAddress localhost = new InetSocketAddress(inetlocalhost, port);
                                      clientSocket.connect(localhost, port);
                                      System.out.println("Client has connected");
                                      //client creates new message from standard input
                                      OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                  }
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  //creating message to send from standard input
                                  String newmessage = "";
                                  try   
                                  {
                                      // input the message from standard input encoded in UTF-8 string format
                                      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                      String line = "";
                                      System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );
                                      while( (line= input.readLine()) != null )     
                                      {
                                          newmessage += line + " ";
                                          input=null;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  catch ( Exception e )
                                  {
                                      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                  }
                                  //Sending the message to server
                                  String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                  try 
                                  {
                                    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                    SocketAddress localhost = null;
                                    clientSocket.connect(localhost, port);
                                    OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                    bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                  } 
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                              }

                          }
                          finally
                          {

                          }

                      }
                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();    
              }
    }
}
```

My question is: How should I go about resolving all three errors (it seems like if I change one part of the code, then the other errors will either still exist or be resolved due to that but I could be wrong)? I would also like to know if there's a way to list the number of clients in an arraylist in the server code  so that when a client closes their window I can keep the server up by just removing them from the list.

Comment: You whousl go about fixing these errors *one at a time.* Too broad.

Comment: @EJP which one would be the most beneficial to focus on or do you think they are all equally detrimental?

Comment: They are all detrimental to the point of fatality, but the array index is trivial and should be fixed first.

Comment: Please paste the stack traces in instead of pasting screen shots.  Also, indicate where the relevant lines are in the code.

Comment: @WarrenDew the stack trace is whatever is inside the console right? like the first screenshot i posted is the stack trace with the red and blue underlined letters?

Comment: The second and third shots are the stack traces, but you should never waste your time and our bandwidth posting pictures of text here.  Post the text. Cut and paste. It's easy.