# Java Error: Exception in thread "Thread-5423" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm creating two program files (one client one server).

Each file has one thread (one thread for server, one thread for client)

At runtime, there is supposed to be only one server, and there is supposed to be multiple and/or potentially infinite number of clients connecting to the server at the same time)

In order to get multiple clients to run, the user opens multiple command prompt / mac terminal windows (each window being one client) (one window being the server, so it requires at least two windows to run)

Once a client is connected, it can send messages (utf-8 strings) to the server. It will also receive from the server all messages sent from the other connected clients (it will not receive messages sent from itself).

For this error, it seems to be triggered by what is in the chat Client.

Screenshot of Client file stacktrace (console in eclipse):

[image]

Code of ChatClient.java (besides args[], I am not sure which array it could be)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatClient
{


    final int numberOfClients = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      ChatClient chatclient = new ChatClient();

              //If I wanted to create multiple clients, would this code go here? OR should the new thread creation be outside the while(true) loop?
              while (true)
              {
                  String host = "localhost";
                  int numberOfClients = 0;
                  Thread ChatClient1 = new Thread ()
                  {
                      public void run()
                      {   
                          try
                          {

                              //Client begins, gets port number, listens, connects, prints out messages from other clients
                              int port = 0;
                              int port_1number1 = 0;
                              int numberofmessages = 0;

                              String[] messagessentbyotherclients = null;
                              System.out.println("Try block begins..");
                              System.out.println("Chat client is running");
                              System.out.println("Port number is: " + args[0]);
                              if(args.length>0)
                              {
                                  port = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                              }
                              System.out.println("Listening for connections..");
                              System.out.println( "Listening on port: " + args[0] );
                              boolean KeepRunning = true;
                              while(KeepRunning)
                              {

                                  System.out.println(messagessentbyotherclients);
                                  try 
                                  {
                                      Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                      InetAddress inetlocalhost = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
                                      SocketAddress localhost = new InetSocketAddress(inetlocalhost, port);
                                      clientSocket.connect(localhost, port);
                                      System.out.println("Client has connected");
                                      //client creates new message from standard input
                                      OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                      OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                      bw.close();
                                      //out.close();
                                      os.close();
                                  }
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  //creating message to send from standard input
                                  String newmessage = "";
                                  try   
                                  {
                                      // input the message from standard input encoded in UTF-8 string format
                                      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                                      String line = "";
                                      System.out.println( "Standard input (press enter then control D when finished): " );
                                      while( (line= input.readLine()) != null )     
                                      {
                                          newmessage += line + " ";
                                          input=null;
                                      }
                                  }
                                  catch ( Exception e )
                                  {
                                      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
                                  }
                                  //Sending the message to server
                                  String sendMessage = newmessage;
                                  try 
                                  {
                                    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", port);
                                    SocketAddress localhost = null;
                                    clientSocket.connect(localhost, port);
                                    OutputStream os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                    bw.write(sendMessage + "\n");
                                    bw.flush();
                                    bw.close();
                                    //out.close();
                                    os.close();
                                    clientSocket.close();
                                  } 
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  System.out.println("Message sent to server: "+sendMessage);
                              }

                          }
                          finally
                          {

                          }

                      }
                  };
                  ChatClient1.start();    
              }
    }
}
```

ChatServer.java code (error not in this, but perhaps will give some context)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.*;
public class ChatServer
{
    ChatServer chatserver = new ChatServer();
    private static Socket socket;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Thread ChatServer1 = new Thread () 
        {
            public void run ()
            {   
                System.out.println("Server thread is now running");
                try
                {
                    int port_number1 = 0;
                    int numberOfClients = 0;
                    boolean KeepRunning = true;
                    if(args.length>0)
                    {
                        port_number1 = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Waiting for connections on port " + port_number1);

                    try 
                    {
                         ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number1);
                         socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println( "Listening for connections on port: " + ( port_number1 ) );
                    while(KeepRunning)
                    {
                        //create a list of clients
                        ArrayList<String> ListOfClients = new ArrayList<String>();

                        //connect to client
                        // socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        //add new client to the list, is this the right way to add a new client? or should it be in a for loop or something?
                        ListOfClients.add("new client");
                        numberOfClients += 1;

                        System.out.println("A client has connected. Waiting for message...");
                        ListOfClients.add("new client" + numberOfClients);

                        //reading encoded utf-8 message from client, decoding from utf-8 format 
                        String MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8 = "";
                        BufferedReader BufReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));  
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedFromUTF8 = BufReader1.readLine();
                        byte[] bytes = MessageFromClientEncodedUTF8.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
                        String MessageFromClientDecodedUTF8 = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");


                        //relaying message to every other client besides the one it was from
                      //  
                      //  for (int i = 0; i < ListOfClients.size(); i++)
                       // {
                            //if(ListOfClients.get(i)!="new client")
                            //{
                                   String newmessage = null;
                                   String returnMessage = newmessage;
                                   OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                                   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                                   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                                   bw.write(returnMessage + "\n");
                                   System.out.println("Message sent to client: "+returnMessage);
                                   bw.flush();
                                   bw.close();
                                  // out.close();
                                   os.close();
                            //}
                        //}

                    }
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (socket != null)
                        {
                            socket.close ();
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        ChatServer1.start();
    }
}
```

My question is: What array is the error being triggered by and/or how to resolve the error? I can't seem to find the location of the error (perhaps it is the args[] but I could be wrong). It is possible that I could just completely delete all arrays in the program, but then I would have to find an alternative method in order to receive the port number from the command line arguments (standard input for port number is not allowed for this unfortunately)

Comment: How did you start the program? Did you provide command-line arguments?  Also, NEVER discard the stack trace like you do in one of your `catch` blocks.  You seem to have `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` occurring in several places, probably all related to `args[]` having length zero.  But you have not provided enough information.

Comment: You were told in your [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553662/java-threads-errors-exception-in-thread-error-plus-array-index-out-of-bounds-ex) not to post pictures of text here.